# Library not Found,library not found for -lopencv_calib3d.3.3

Tags: ios, iphone

Ld build/Release-iphoneos/Demo.app/Demo normal arm64
    cd /Users/meitu/Desktop/Demo3
    export  IPHONEO _ DEPLOYMENT _  TARGET=11.0

Comment: Try changing your project's minimum deployment target to 9.0 if not and install pod again.

Answer (score 0):

you have to install the debug version of OpenCV 3.3.

If you use cmake follow the instruction given by
https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_gcc_cmake/linux_gcc_cmake.html

For integration into a makefile under linux you can use the useful commands
pkg-config --cflags opencv
pkg-config --libs opencv
in your Makefile.

Maybe you must compile openCV by yourself setting the debug option.

Comment: 我安装的opencv是最新版的，错误提示是找不到库，我接下来该做什么来解决这个问题？